# What is the difference between object and object() in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, instantiation, most-vexing-parse

```
class A {
  public:
    A() { cout << "Constructor\n"; }  // (1) default constructor
};

A obj;                                // (2) instantiating obj

A obj();                              // (3)
```

What is the difference between instantiating `obj` and `obj()`? `obj` calls the default constructor   (1) mentioned above. Which constructor will `obj()` call?

Comment: @Thank you all for the links..

Answer (score 1):

`A obj();` declares a function called `obj` which takes no arguments and which returns an `A`. It does not declare an `A` object at all.

As `A obj();` does not declare an `A` object, it does not result in any constructor call.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is declared as a function. the name of the function is obj. It takes no arguments. It returns the object of type A.